# Needs VBA solution - Clear contents of 4 cells to left of cell with N/A Error

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, vba, vlookup

I have a table of data in which column L has a vlookup formula. In the rows where column L (i.e., the vlookup returns "#N/A"), I would like to clear the contents of the eight cells to the left (columns D through K). I would like to create a VBA macro to do this. Any help is much appreciated.

Here is my code right now:

```
Dim r As Range
Dim i As Long
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("1yr Matcher").Select
For i = 7 To 500
    For Each r In Range(Cells(10, i), Cells(Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row, i))
        If IsError(r) Then
            If r >= 0 Then r.Offset(, -1).Resize(, -8).ClearContents
        End If
    Next r
Next
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please see [ask] to help you write good questions. We are not a "please write my code" resource but we're very willing to help you when you get stuck. What have you tried so far? How far have you gotten in the code? Do you get an error message on a particular line? Are you getting unexpected results?

Comment: Dim r As Range
    Dim i As Long
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
    For i = 7 To 500
        For Each r In Range(Cells(10, i), Cells(Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row, i))
            If IsError(r) Then
                If r >= 0 Then r.Offset(, -1).Resize(, -8).ClearContents
            End If
        Next r
    Next

Comment: That is how far I've gotten.

Comment: It's also better to edit your question than add code to comments which have very limited formatting capability. Improving the quality of your question makes it easier for others to read.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your `For` statements. Right now, the value for `r` iterates through {`G1`, `G2`, ..., `G10`} and then {`H1`, ..., `H10`} and all the way up to {`SF1`, ... `SF10`}. It looks like you want to loop through all the cells in `L7:L500` so why not do that directly?

```
Dim r As Range
For Each r In Range("L7:L500")
    If IsError(r) Then
        If r >= 0 Then r.Offset(, -1).Resize(, -8).ClearContents
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
Sub ErrorCleaner()
    Dim r As Range, rng As Range, L As Long
    Set rng = Range("L:L").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors)
    For Each r In rng
        If r.Text = "#N/A" Then
            L = r.Row
            Range(Cells(L, "D"), Cells(L, "K")).Clear
    End If
    Next r
End Sub
```